# How do I pass a xml attribute to xslt parameter?

Tags: asp.net, xml, xslt, xmldatasource

I got everything working (thank empo) except the ctrlname column. I don't know the syntax well enough. What I am trying to do is use the xslt to sort the xml in the gridview by the column name. Everything is working but the ctrlname column. How do I pass an attribute to the XSLT? I've tried: @name, Data/@name, Data[@name], ctrlname. Nothing works.

```
    XmlDataSource1.EnableCaching = False
    Dim xslTrnsform As System.Xml.Xsl.XsltArgumentList = New System.Xml.Xsl.XsltArgumentList
    xslTrnsform.AddParam("sortby", "", sortAttr)
    xslTrnsform.AddParam("orderas", "", orderby)
    XmlDataSource1.TransformArgumentList = xslTrnsform
    XmlDataSource1.DataFile = "~/App_LocalResources/DST_Test.xml"
    XmlDataSource1.XPath = "//data"
    XmlDataSource1.TransformFile = xsltFileName
    'XmlDataSource1.DataBind()
    GridView1.DataSource = XmlDataSource1
    GridView1.DataBind()
```

XSL

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">

    <xsl:param name="sortby"></xsl:param>
    <xsl:param name="orderas"></xsl:param>

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <!--<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>-->
    <xsl:template match="root">
        <root>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="data">
                <xsl:sort select="*[name()=$sortby]" data-type="text" order="{$orderas}"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </root>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="data">
        <data>
            <xsl:attribute name="ctrlname">
                <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="value">
                <xsl:value-of select="value" />
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="comment">
                <xsl:value-of select="comment" />
            </xsl:attribute>
        </data>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

XML input

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<root>
    <data name="Test1.Text" xml:space="preserve">
        <value>Please Pick Bare Pump</value>
        <comment>Tab - Pump Configuration</comment>
    </data>
    <data name="Test2.Text" xml:space="preserve">
        <value>Complete</value>
        <comment>A07</comment>
    </data>
    <data name="Test3.Text" xml:space="preserve">
        <value>Confirmed</value>
        <comment>A01</comment>
    </data>
</root>
```

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a more powerful and generic solution that is shorter and allows to sort correctly even in the case when there is an attribute and a child element with the same name. :)

Comment: I also provided detailed explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I'm sorry didnt notice that you wanted also sort by attributes. Note also that you have changed the syntax of `xsl:param` and it's not correct in that way. It's very important that you keep the single quotes inside the double ones. Here is the final template:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">

        <xsl:param name="sortby" select="'value'"/>
        <xsl:param name="orderas" select="'ascending'"/>

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <!--<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>-->
    <xsl:template match="root">
        <root>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="data">
                <xsl:sort select="*[name()=$sortby]|@*[name()=$sortby]" data-type="text" order="{$orderas}"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </root>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="data">
        <data>
            <xsl:attribute name="ctrlname">
                <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="value">
                <xsl:value-of select="value" />
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="comment">
                <xsl:value-of select="comment" />
            </xsl:attribute>
        </data>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks! I don't know if the XslArgumentList is the reason I don't need the select values for the xsl:params. But in my current code, I don't have select values and it works just fine. But I'll alter my code to match your code. Since your code is correct.

Answer (score 2):

**The currently accepted answer has one flaw**: Whenever there is an attribute of `data` with the same name as a child element of `data`, the sort will always be performed using as keys the values of the attribute. Also, it is too long.

**This solution solves the problem** (and is shorter) allowing to specify whether the sort should be by attribute-name or by element-name:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:param name="sortby" select="'attrib!name'"/>
    <xsl:param name="orderas" select="'ascending'"/>
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="root">
        <root>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="data">
                <xsl:sort select=
                "*[name()=substring-after($sortby, 'elem!')]
                |
                 @*[name()=substring-after($sortby, 'attrib!')]"
                data-type="text" order="{$orderas}"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </root>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="data">
        <data ctrlname="{@name}" value="{value}"
              comment="{comment}"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When applied on this XML document** (based on the provided one, but made a little-bit more interesting):

```
<root>
    <data name="Test3.Text" xml:space="preserve">
        <value>Please Pick Bare Pump</value>
        <comment>Tab - Pump Configuration</comment>
        <name>X</name>
    </data>
    <data name="Test2.Text" xml:space="preserve">
        <value>Complete</value>
        <comment>A07</comment>
        <name>Z</name>
    </data>
    <data name="Test1.Text" xml:space="preserve">
        <value>Confirmed</value>
        <comment>A01</comment>
        <name>Y</name>
    </data>
</root>
```

**the correct result (sorted by the `name` attribute) is produced**:

```
<root>
   <data ctrlname="Test1.Text" value="Confirmed" comment="A01"/>
   <data ctrlname="Test2.Text" value="Complete" comment="A07"/>
   <data ctrlname="Test3.Text" value="Please Pick Bare Pump" comment="Tab - Pump Configuration"/>
</root>
```

**Now, replace the `<xsl:param name="sortby" select="'attrib!name'"/>` with**:

```
<xsl:param name="sortby" select="'elem!name'"/>
```

**and apply the transformation again on the same XML document. This time we get the result correctly sorted by the values of the child-*element* `name`:**

```
<root>
   <data ctrlname="Test3.Text" value="Please Pick Bare Pump" comment="Tab - Pump Configuration"/>
   <data ctrlname="Test1.Text" value="Confirmed" comment="A01"/>
   <data ctrlname="Test2.Text" value="Complete" comment="A07"/>
</root>
```

**Explanation**:

1. To distinguish whether we want to sort by an element-child or by an attribute, we use the convention that `elem!someName` means the sort must be by the values of a child element named `someName`. Similarly, `attrib!someName` means the sort must be by the values of an attribute named `someName`.
2. The `<xsl:sort>` insruction is modified accordingly to select as key correctly either an attribute or a child element. No ambiguity is allowed, because the starting substring of the `sortby` parameter now uniquely identifies whether the key should be an attribute or a child element.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I think this should work for you, allowing you to specify either attribute or element names in the $sortby parameter:

```
<xsl:template match="root">
    <root>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="data">
            <xsl:sort select="*[name()=$sortby] | @*[name()=$sortby]" data-type="text" order="{$orderas}"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </root>
</xsl:template>
```

(you would just pass in "name" as the value of the $sortby parameter)

The problem was that the sort value node selection was only matching elements (`*` matches elements only).

Comment: I wish I could mark you as the answer too. Someone +1 this guy! Thanks, Tao.