# pass attribue values of tags of xml using xslt

Tags: c#, html, xml, xslt

I am new to xslt. I have following xml and xslt which i need to convert into html using XslCompiledTranform.
I have following XML

```
<ref-list id="RL10">
 <label>
  <bold>7.0</bold>
 </label>
 <title>
  <bold>References</bold>
 </title>
  <ref id="R66" content-type="references">
   <label>2</label>
    <mixed-citation publication-type="book">
     <person-group person-group-type="author">
      <name>
       <surname>Chown,</surname>
       <given-names>Bill</given-names>
      </name>
     </person-group>, and
     <person-group person-group-type="author">
      <name>
       <surname>Lange</surname>
       <given-names>Michelle</given-names>
      </name>
     </person-group>. &#x201C;
     <source>Modernizing System Development: Requirements&#x002d;Based, Model&#x002d;Driven Design, Implementation and Test</source>.&#x201D;
     <publisher-name>Mentor Graphics Corp., ERTS</publisher-name>,
     <month>Feb.</month>
     <year>2012</year>.
    </mixed-citation></ref>
    <ref id="R67" content-type="references">
     <label>3</label>
      <mixed-citation publication-type="journal">
       <person-group person-group-type="author">
        <name>
         <surname>Blyler,</surname>
         <given-names>John</given-names>
        </name>
       </person-group>. &#x201C;
       <article-title>Model&#x002d;Driven Development Is Key to Low Power</article-title>.&#x201D; 
       <source>Chip Design Magazine &#x002d; JB&#x2019;s Circuit</source>,
       <month>Dec.</month>
       <day>6</day>,
       <year>2012</year>.
       <uri xlink:href="http://www.chipdesignmag.com/blyler/2012/12/06/model-driven-development-key-to-low-power/">http:&#x002F;&#x002F;www.chipdesignmag.com&#x002F;blyler&#x002F;2012&#x002F;12&#x002F;06&#x002F;model&#x002d;driven&#x002d;development&#x002d;key&#x002d;to&#x002d;low&#x002d;power&#x002F;</uri>.
      </mixed-citation>
     </ref>
 </ref-list>
```

I have the following xslt

```
<xsl:template match="ref-list/ref">
  <html>
   <head></head>
   <body>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
   </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ref-list/ref">
  <p>
    <xsl:value-of select="label"/>
    <xsl:for-each select="mixed-citation">
          <xsl:for-each select="person-group/name">
            <xsl:value-of select="given-names"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="surnames"/>
          </xsl:for-each>
      <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="source"/>
      <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="publisher-name"/>
      <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="day"/>
      <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="month"/>
      <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="year"/>
      <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
      <xsl:for-each select="uri">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      </xsl:for-each>
      <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="article-title"/>
      <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="publisher-loc"/>
      <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="volume"/>
      <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="issue"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </p>
</xsl:template>
```

I have to transform my xml to html using xslt. But while transforming, it is saying that 'xlink' is an undeclared prefix. I dont know how to parse it. 
I need the output that parse uri tag having xlink as its attribute.I dont know how to parse any attribute of the any xml tag. Can anyone please explain how to parse any xml tags having its attributes ?

Comment: See these resource:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8352947/passing-xml-attribute-value-to-html-atrribute-value-using-xslt

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13090401/using-xsl-to-pass-an-xml-attribute-as-an-id-into-html

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6050044/how-do-i-pass-a-xml-attribute-to-xslt-parameter

Comment: I don't know where i am going wrong, but still i am getting the same error. Error says that xlink is not declared in Xml. There is a way where we can exclude prefixes, but i don't know how to do it. May be that can resolve my problem.Is there any way in xslt where i can exclude prefixes i.e. xlink ?

Comment: It is called a namespace. The root tag of your xml should contain `xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"`. If not it should be included everytime you add `xlink:href` in you tag.

Comment: This is definitely the problem - you should add this as answer @Joel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is called a namespace. The root tag of your xml should contain

```
xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink
```

If not it should be included everytime you add `xlink:href` in you tag.

Comment: but after this namespace as <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"?> i am getting this error "The ":" character , hexadecimal values 0*3A, cannot be included in a name. Line 1, position 43.

Comment: not the xml declaration, the tag after that is the root tag.